# React native signed apk build failed lint error

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

Facing this error while building signed apk of react native app. Searched many solutions on the internet but nothing worked. Tried to put this in app's gradle file with no luck

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
```

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-navigation:lintClassPath'.

> Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.2.
>         Searched in the following locations:
>             file:/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.pom
>             file:/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.jar
>             file:/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.pom
>             file:/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.jar
>             file:/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.pom
>             file:/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.jar
>             file:/Users/apple/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.pom
>             file:/Users/apple/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.jar
>             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.pom
>             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.jar
>             file:/Users/apple/Desktop/wecora/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.pom
>             file:/Users/apple/Desktop/wecora/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/tools/lint/lint/26.1.2/lint-26.1.2.jar
>         Required by:
>             project :react-native-navigation > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 40s
85 actionable tasks: 81 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem, I solved it by adding 
`maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in project's gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```